# Display newly added field value of account settings

Tags: drupal-7, custom-fields, user-accounts

I added a new field(First name) in Account settings & its machine name is 'field_first_name'
I am trying to load this value in home page like this

```
<?php print $user->field_first_name ?>
```

But the above code is not working.

Comment: 1) If this is a custom php script, have you added the drupal API?

2) If this is on the drupal CMS, have you enabled the PHP filter?

Answer (score -1):

Display Suite for Drupal 7 - Part 3: Fields

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvFP16PJt4c